# Drop Down With Text Input Option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to implement onto my website a drop down style menu of which also has a text input field to add your own option aside from the predefined provided options. I have an example of this via the images below;

### Drop Down Example - Closed

[image: Drop Down Example - Closed]

### Drop Down Example - Open

[image: Drop Down Example - Open]

What is my best solution to achieve this result for my website?

Comment: To start off, it would be a good solution to give it a try and see what you can come up with, then we can point you in the right direction (if necessary).

Comment: @Gacci To be honest, I would not know where to start. I know how to make a drop down list and I use a JQuery plugin to make it look nice. I also know how to make a text input field, however to merge both like so, is a different ball park for me.

Comment: Surly people do not want me to post with a basic drop menu and text box as this should be common knowledge for someone trying to achieve more, if you could be more specific to as how I could edit my question, I would be very grateful.

Comment: He's just saying show some effort, that's all. Posting a copy/pasted drop down isn't effort, it's just doing the minimum to try and solicit a solution without even really trying first. I'd bet if you did some googling you'd come up with an idea.

Comment: The only thing Google has shown myself is merging both in which you have a drop icon and/or you can enter text, like a predicted field, none of which show how to have a text field as one of the drop options. I'm not looking for a direct answer as such, along the lines and then I can then post what I have come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a jquery plugin called chosen by harvest that handles this well. It allows free form input on the dropdown, and many other options. It's docs are here: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Once it's installed you can use something like this to initialize it on your select box.

```
 $(".chosen-select").chosen();
```

Comment: Really nice plugin however these are only search fields in a drop menu. Although a search is nice, I must allow for the entered word(s) to be chosen even if no results (for the Single Select with Groups)

Comment: That option is available as well, you'd just need to look through the documentation for it.

Comment: Is it? Sorry, I must confess, I just had a glance through the examples page. In this case, this is absolutely perfect for what I need. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

[Select2](http://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/)

[Selectivity (formerly Select3)](https://github.com/arendjr/selectivity)

[fSelect (lightweight)](https://github.com/mgibbs189/fSelect)